# Why can't I decode the zhihu.com response using urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()?

Tags: python, unicode, urllib, python-3.4

I found the following example in the [Python `urllib.request` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen('http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl') as response:
    for line in response:
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if 'EST' in line or 'EDT' in line:
             print(line)
```

This outputs

```
Nov. 25, 09:43:32 PM EST
```

I tried to copy that code for use with a Chinese site:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.zhihu.com'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
print(response)
```

but I get an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The site returns a gzipped response, even though you did not request one:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> url = 'http://www.zhihu.com'
>>> response = urlopen(url)
>>> response.info().get('Content-Encoding')
'gzip'
```

This is a violation of the HTTP RFCs, the site does this even when you specifically disallow it:

```
>>> from urllib.request import Request
>>> response = urlopen(Request(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity,gzip;q=0'}))
>>> response.info().get('Content-Encoding')
'gzip'
```

You'll have to decompress the response data first, only then can you decode the resulting bytes as UTF-8:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(response.read(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
>>> print(*decompressed_data.decode('utf8').splitlines(True)[:10])
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="zh-CN">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=432274380">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
 <meta name="renderer" content="webkit" />
 <meta name="description" content="一个真实的网络问答社区，帮助你寻找答案，分享知识。"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
 <title>知乎 - 与世界分享你的知识、经验和见解</title>
```